# CellValueChanged and Checkbox issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the below code to detect changes on cells and then do a update, but I am having one column of checkbox for detele.

The problem is when I check the checkbox, it will also means that the cell value had been changed.
Is there a workaround on this or is there a stop/end cellvaluechanged command or cellvaluechanged only for certain cells/rows/columns?

Thanks.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
    { 
        myDataGridView.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler( 
        myDataGridView_CellValueChanged); 
    } 

    private void myDataGridView_CellValueChanged( 
    object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
    { 
       //some very crude examples of actions you might want to perform when the event handler is triggered. 
       myObject.update(); 
       //or something else like 
       myObject.isUpdatable = true; 
    }
```

Comment: I suppose you could do something like drop your cellvaluechanged method in a if statement.. Then for the if statement check if the eventargs are a checkbox.checked if false then                      { 
       //some very crude examples of actions you might want to perform when the event handler is triggered. 
       myObject.update(); 
       //or something else like 
       myObject.isUpdatable = true; 
    }        if its true it will skip it.. If its false it will execute.. Sorry I know very little about Csharp I am a VB guy myself but that will work for you..

Answer (score 0):

You only have to check for the ColumnIndex from the DataGridViewCellEventArgs parameter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.aspx

Comment: I got it.
Thanks all...

    private void dgv_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
      if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name!="Delete")
      {
         Actions... ...
      }
    }